# How to launch Spotify using a command through the dock

Tags: command-line, shortcuts, dock, spotify

I recently installed Ubuntu on my laptop, and Spotify's fonts were too small to be legible. I was able to fix it by launching it though the terminal using this command
`spotify --force-device-scale-factor=2`

But launching it from the icon on the dock will go back to the tiny font. How do I get Spotify to launch using that command through the icon on the dock?

I just today upgraded from 19.10 to the 20.04 beta, but nothing changed on that end.

Answer (score 1):

- Open a terminal
- Edit the file /usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop (sudo editor /usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop)
- Replace the line 'Exec=spotify %U' with 'Exec=spotify --force-device-scale-factor=2 %U'

Answer (score 0):

I did:
cd /
sudo find . -type f -name "spotify*"
The file for me was:
./var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop

I use vim:
sudo vim ./var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop

Replaced:
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop /snap/bin/spotify %U
With:
Exec=env BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT=/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/spotify_spotify.desktop /snap/bin/spotify --force-device-scale-factor=2 %U

After saving, I clicked on the spotify icon and the font was still too small, so I went back and used the command line. However, later when I clicked on the icon again, it worked and opened it at the scale factor of 2. Not sure why it didn't work the first time.